# Error: Edit is only valid while callback runs

Tags: javascript, vscode-extensions

I am using `showInputBox()` to take input from the user in VsCode extension and using the `edit.insert()` method to display the result according to the user's input.

It is throwing error: `Edit is only valid while callback runs`.

Here is my code snipet:

`vscode.window.showInputBox({placeHolder: 'number of paragraphs needed'}).then(value => { edit.insert(selection.start, randomPara(value));})`

I want the edit text to work according to the input provided by the user.

I have also tried using `await` but it throws the error `await is only valid in async function.`

Answer (score 0):

This question got answered here: [vscode github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/78066). A pre-existing `edit` object cannot be used inside a `then` or after an `await`. In these use cases, you need to create a new `edit` object.